# Is it needed to update in-app purchases for new updated version of the application?

Tags: ios, app-store, in-app-purchase

I am trying to prepare new update for my application. But a can't select in-app items on iTunes Connect for updated version. Is old items prepared for my last version will be available in this new updated version? Or I need to resubmit items for review again?

Answer (score 0):

IApps are reviewed separately from a normal application.  Once they have been approved, they stay approved through any new versions of your application that you submit, and only go back for review when you modify or add an item.